# Does React rerender all the components of a FOR loop if the array changes but some of the keys remain the same?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm implementing infinite scroll of videos. Each component has a unique id im using as the key. Each component will be very large so i want to only keep a couple items on the DOM at a time. For example if i have 5 elements with id A,B,C,D,E and next state is B,C,D,E,F will B,C,D,E be rerendered by React?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends what you mean with re rendered, re generate jsx or re creating and replacing the DOM elements.

The jsx is re created when:

1. When the parent creates new jsx and the child is a functional component (not wrapped in React.memo) the child will re create jsx because functional components always re create jsx.
2. When the parent re creates jsx and passes the child different prop values than the previous render.
3. When value in `[value,setValue]=useState()` or when `this.state` changes (when state changes).
4. When value in `value = useContext(someContext)` changes.
5. In most cases when value in `value = useCustomHook()` changes but this is not guaranteed for every hook.
6. When Parent renders and passes a different key prop to Child than the previous render (see 2). This causes the Child to unmount and re mount as well.

Creating new jsx does not mean that DOM elements are recreated, after creating jsx (virtual dom) React will compare this to the actual DOM and only update actual DOM if it changed. This compare cycle can be optimized by memoizing the jsx using React.memo, React.useMemo and reselect.

With props changing value between renders I mean that the reference has changed for objects or value for primitives. So `propName={{new:'object'}}` and `propName={{new:'object'}}` will be different. The virtual dom (jsx) created will likely be the same as the DOM so the component will not actually render. But when you do something like `onClick={new=>'function'}` then virtual dom compare will always fail, that is why useCallback is used.

Answer (score 0):

> will B,C,D,E be rerendered by React?

Technically yes, but for enhanced performance React uses a virtual DOM, when state changes occur, the virtual DOM is updated and the previous and current version of virtual DOM is compared, finally React sends a batch update to the real DOM to update the UI. Meaning that it will render only the elements that had changed into the real DOM.